# str makes a string of its enclosed map

Tags: dictionary, clojure, lazy-evaluation

When I `map` inside `str`, I get a stringification of `clojure.lang.LazySeq`.

```
user=> (str (map inc (range 3)))
"clojure.lang.LazySeq@7861"
```

I've found and tried many answers - `apply`, `doall`, `doseq`, different mappings, mapping custom functions that use `doall` and other things, trying different repls, etc. - but can't seem to get `map` to eval before being stringified.

Update: This should also work in more general case uses of `str`:

```
user=> (str "pre string " (map inc (range 3)) " post string")
```

Desired output:

```
user=> "pre string 123 post string"
```

Comment: Show us your desired output.

Comment: please change `(map inc range 3)` to `(map inc (range 3))` in `(str "pre string " (map inc range 3) " post string")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like this?

```
(apply str (map inc (range 3)))
=> "123"
```

Show us your desired output to make sure that we are on the same page.

Still, I don't know what is your desired output.

```
(str "pre string " (apply str (map inc (range 3))) " post string")
=> "pre string 123 post string"
```

Comment: This works for this specific use of `str`. I need it for more general use cases, too. I've updated the question with the additional info.

Comment: That solves it. You got the desired output, even though I hadn't yet posted it. I edited the question to add it, for posterity. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

use *seq*

```
(str (seq (map inc (range 3))))
"(1 2 3)"
```

Comment: This is a good solution for when I want the form itself printed. Thanks!